# Как пишется частица "таки"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, дефис

В каких случаях частица "таки" пишется раздельно, а в каких — через дефис?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Через дефис частица "таки" пишется только с глаголами и наречиями. С остальными словами она пишется раздельно.
Примеры: *прямо-таки, все-таки, Украина перешла-таки на зимнее время, он таки выиграл в лотерею*.

Answer (score 4):

> Частица ТАКИ пишется через дефис только после наречий (ПРЯМО-ТАКИ), глаголов (ПРИШЕЛ-ТАКИ) и других частиц (НЕУЖЕЛИ-ТАКИ), а в остальных случаях пишется отдельно (ОН ТАКИ УСПЕЛ ВОЙТИ В ВАГОН).

Кроме того, к частице "таки" применимо и следующее правило для частиц вообще:

> Если частица, которая пишется через дефис, стоит после другой частицы, то дефис не ставится, например: ВСЕ ЖЕ ТАКИ, ОН БЫ ДЕ ЭТОГО НЕ СКАЗАЛ. Сказанное не касается частицы -С, например: КАК ЖЕ-С. Если же частицы -ТО, -ДЕ, -ТАКИ находятся внутри сложного слова, части которого соединены дефисом, то дефис пишется только перед частицей, а после нее опускается, например: ПОДОБРУ-ТО ПОЗДОРОВУ, ПОСТОЯЛ-ТАКИ ПОСТОЯЛ И УШЕЛ.

Источник: [грамота.ру "Правописание частиц"](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_122)

Answer (score 1):

Полный ответ дает [Орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8):

> таки - частица, пишется через дефис с предшествующим глаголом (вернулся-таки), наречием (довольно-таки, прямо-таки) и в словах всё-таки, так-таки; в остальных случаях – раздельно (он таки приедет)

Answer (score 0):

***Частица таки пишется через дефис в составе слов все-таки и так-таки, а также в тех случаях, когда она следует за глаголом, например:**

- Узнал-таки меня? Во всех остальных
     случаях частица таки пишется
     отдельно, например: Я таки думаю
     кое-что (М. Горький). И все ж таки я
     тебя не понимаю.*