# Нужна ли запятая при цитировании?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот, цитирование

Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что «лесные монстры, пугающие граждан»(,) не могут существовать.

Comment: Мне интересно стало. Вот вы, например, сколько видите ответов на этот [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29/Как-пишется-частица-таки), есть ли там удаленный ответ на розовом фоне?  И видите ли вы свой сегодяшний удаленный ответ?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, по вашей ссылке мне доступны четыре ответа (все на белом фоне). По второму вопросу: свой удаленный ответ я вижу на розовом фоне (в том числе доступна кнопка восстановления).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что правильнее без запятой.

Есть более общее правило:
Поглощаться могут только запятая или тире как части парного, выделяющего знака. Они всегда поглощаются точкой, вопросительным и восклицательным знаком, многоточием, точкой с запятой, последующей закрывающей скобкой или **последующими закрывающими кавычками** как знаками большего значения.
*Пети не было дома (он пошел к товарищу, с которым намеревался из ополченцев перейти в действующую армию).* Здесь закрывающая запятая придаточного предложения поглощается скобкой вставной конструкции.
https://findout.su/3x32472.html

*как части парного, выделяющего знака* — так понимаю, что речь о том, когда парными запятыми или тире обособляем что-то.

Как здесь получается: в конце причастного оборота должна стоять запятая, но в этом месте стоят закрывающие кавычки, которые её поглощают. Но запятая однозначно сохраняется, если она нужна по условиям контекста (то есть никак не связана с цитатой), как в примере про мысль Толстого.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 5):

**Второй ответ**

Размахиваю крыльями, качаю головой и — признаюсь в своей ошибке. (Предыдущий ответ не удаляю, чтобы была видна история заблуждений.)
**Не нужна** указанная запятая (после причастного оборота)!

Вот правильное решение (спасибо настырному *oleedd*’у, навел на мысль):

> 6. Если предложение или словосочетание, заключенное в кавычки, должно было бы заканчиваться запятой, а дальше следует продолжение текста, то запятая не ставится ни перед закрывающими кавычками, ни после них, например: *Стихи «Ты знаешь край, где все обильем дышит» знакомы нам с детства; **Но вот пришло время, когда «старик, одержимый рисунком» уже не мог держать кисть.*** Запятая не опускается перед открывающими кавычками, например: *Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы»*.

[Сочетания знаков препинания](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm) (§135. Кавычки и другие знаки)

Comment: Даже лайк поставлю, за этот пример. Разные редакции справочника — разные примеры.

Comment: Что смешно: что в самом произведении ("Одержимый рисунком") запятая стоит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Случайно наткнулся на это правило Розенталя:
Если предложение, заключенное в кавычки, должно было бы заканчиваться запятой, а дальше следует текст, то запятая не ставится ни перед закрывающими кавычками, ни после них. Например:
*В такт песенке «В лесу, где много елочек» дети сгибали правую руку.* Запятая не опускается перед открывающими кавычками, например: *Угадайте, «кто стучится в дверь ко мне с толстой сумкой на ремне, с цифрой «5» на медной бляшке, в синей форменной фуражке».*

Да, пример не такой (прописная, а не строчная), но, как видим, Розенталь не разделяет в данном правиле цитаты с прописной и цитаты со строчной (именно так оформлен текст правила).

Comment: Здесь, конечно, все правильно. *В такт песенке «В лесу, где много елочек» дети сгибали правую руку*. Но это совсем не то! «В лесу, где много елочек» — это **название** песни. Фраза не является полноценной частью, компонентом предложения. Мы это название можем спокойно выбросить: *В такт песенке дети сгибали правую руку*. В нашем же предложении мы этого сделать "не могём": *Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что не могут существовать.*

Comment: Да, знаю, поэтому добавил абзац после правила.

Comment: Этот абзац никак не лепится. *...Розенталь не разделяет в данном правиле цитаты с прописной и цитаты со строчной...* Ну НЕТ в первом предложении цитаты.

Comment: В первом предложении цитаты тоже имеются в виду.

Answer (score 3):

Теперь о логике.

Раз оборот начался внутри кавычек, то и закрыть его надо внутри кавычек:
*Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что «лесные монстры, пугающие граждан,» не могут существовать.* || Но так нельзя, потому что больше в кавычках нет текста, поэтому запятую надо убрать. Но такое возможно, если вставка:
*Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что оно — лесные монстры, пугающие граждан, — не может существовать.* || Закрывающая запятая остаётся.
Да, синтаксическая связь есть, она заключается в согласовании со сказуемым, но она не настолько сильная (потому что в цитате чужеродный текст), чтобы действовать, как обычно.

Как и со скобками:
*Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что они [лесные монстры, пугающие граждан] не могут существовать.* || Без закрывающей запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения!

Answer (score 2):

*Андрей знал, что женщина врала, потому что «лесные монстры, пугающие граждан», не могут существовать.*

Я думаю, что пунктуационно предложение оформлено правильно.
Ориентируемся на то, что имеется в [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137):

> § 143. Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется **кавычками** (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением: *Мысль Л. Н. Толстого «время есть отношение движения своей жизни к движению других существ», высказанная в его дневниках, имеет философское содержание.*

Цитата синтаксически связана с авторским текстом, входит в придаточное предложение, имеет причастный оборот (а его надо "закрыть") —  запятая после цитаты нужна.

P. S. В предложении нет деепричастного оборота, поэтому я исправила и формулировку вопроса, и метки.

**Объяснения**
В комментарии, конечно же, я ничего не добавляла в цитату, а написала "предположим".
Предположим, что текст, из которого была взята цитата, имеет такой вид:
*Лесные монстры, пугающие граждан безлунной ночью, исчезают на рассвете.*
Или такой:
*Лесные монстры, пугающие граждан: леший, кикимора, чупакабра...*

В первом предложении запятой после "граждан" нет, во втором имеется двоеточие.
При встраивании цитируемого кусочка в авторское предложение (этот кусочек теперь становится полноценной его частью) знаки нужны те, которые диктуются обычными правилами. Ставим запятую после причастного оборота.

Цитата из правила ([Л. Н. Толстой. Дневники. 1901 г.](https://rvb.ru/tolstoy/01text/vol_22/1488.htm)):
«Время есть отношение движения своей жизни к движению других существ».
Включаем ее в авторское предложение, после цитаты ставим не точку, а запятую, так как далее идет причастный оборот (*высказанная в его дневниках*).
В отсутствие же причастного оборота никакой знак после цитаты не нужен.

Comment: *знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением* — может, имеется в виду то, что вокруг цитаты. Оно же однозначно о том, что не все знаки употребляются. Какие же тогда не употребляются?

Comment: Читаю попеременно «Трое в лодке, не считая собаки» и «Собаку Баскервилей» (читаю «Т» и «С» — без запятой). Читаю попеременно «Трое в лодке, не считая собаки», «Собаку Баскервилей» (читаю «Т», «С» — с запятой, потому она необходима в авторском предложении).

Comment: Ну так в примере из вопроса запятая тоже к цитате относится. Да и в правиле речь о цитатах со строчной.

Comment: Не только о цитатах со строчной. Прочитайте внимательно: *знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением*.

Comment: @oleedd *Ну так в примере из вопроса запятая тоже к цитате относится*. Нет, запятая относится к авторскому предложению. Предположим: ***Лесные монстры, пугающие граждан** темной безлунной ночью, исчезают на рассвете*. В этом предложении после "граждан" запятой нет, а в авторском — есть.

Comment: Прочитайте правило, которое вы привели, там сказано о строчной. Вы просто расширили цитату, цитату не используют, добавляя к ней свой текст так, у вас каша получилась, более того, считаю, что ваш пример некорректен: *«Лесные монстры, пугающие граждан» темной безлунной ночью, исчезают на рассвете.* К цитате так нельзя добавлять обстоятельство, потому что это слова другого человека, оборот не ваш, чтобы к нему что-то добавлять. Эта запятая закрывает оборот, который внутри цитаты, к остальному предложению она отношения не имеет: *...потому что «лесные монстры» не могут существовать.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако после обсуждения с @oleedd я в СМЯТЕНИИ.

Comment: *Предположим, что текст, из которого была взята цитата, имеет такой вид* — этого вы не говорили, поэтому и не понял. Это ничего не меняет. В примере Толстого оборот после цитаты, поэтому запятая, а в примере из вопроса оборот в цитате, поэтому эта запятая не имеет отношения к остальному предложению, то есть этот знак не диктуется самим авторским предложением (в правиле не сказано о сохранении всех знаков, там написано "только те"). К чему веду: что приведённое вами правило против вас.

Comment: Вы, похоже, не очень понимаете. Мы в любом случае не можем цитировать вторую запятую (даже если она идёт дальше), поэтому не играет роли, есть ли она в тексте, из которого была взята цитата. А к авторскому предложению знак относится тогда, когда нужен из-за того, что идёт дальше, а не из-за того, что было до (в цитате).

Comment: *после цитаты ставим не точку, а запятую, так как далее идет причастный оборот* — если следовать вашей логике, то в примере из вопроса ставим не запятую, а ничего, так как далее нет ничего, что требовало бы постановки запятой. Что не так?

Comment: Не так. Мы не знаем, какой знак был в полном предложении после слова "граждан" (я привела только два варианта). В нашем — новом — предложении мы расставляем знаки, невзирая на прежнюю пунктуацию.

Comment: Без разницы, какой там был знак, мы же говорим о знаке после кавычки, а не до. *В нашем — новом — предложении мы расставляем знаки, невзирая на прежнюю пунктуацию* — мне ваша точка зрения ясна (ставить знаки, как обычно), только вот правило против вас, там сказано "только те", а не все. Эта запятая диктуется непосредственно цитатой (потому что оборот в ней), а не остальным предложением.

Comment: Спасибо за обсуждение. Почитав ответ @oleedd, я все же склоняюсь к его варианту. Пример с  Толстым действительно немного не подходит к моему вопросу, так как запятая не относится к самой цитате.