# Цитирование оборотов

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, деепричастный-оборот, сравнительный-оборот, цитирование

В каких случаях и для чего стоит обособлять кавычками сравнительный или другой оборот (деепричастный об., вводную конструкцию...), если они использованы в чужом тексте?

```
> Пример текста: "Я, обливаясь кровью, встал на стул как висельник". 
> Использование цитирования: Так, автор показывает, что мужчина "обливаясь кровью" готов уйти из мира "как висельник".
```

Какие знаки препинания допустимы? Необходимы? Рекомендованы? Почему и по какому правилу?

Comment: Обособляют запятыми, а в кавычки заключают или берут.

Comment: обособлять (разделять, вычленять, выделять, изолировать) можно многими способами, а так чаще заключать в кавычки, конечно

Comment: Принятый ответ неверный. Детали в комментариях.

Comment: "Обливаясь кровью" — это фразеологизм или он реально был окровавленным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **6.** Если предложение или словосочетание, заключенное в кавычки, должно было бы заканчиваться запятой, но дальше следует продолжение текста, то запятая не ставится ни перед закрывающими кавычками, ни после них: *Стихи «Ты знаешь край, где всё обильем дышит» знакомы нам с детства; Но вот пришло время, когда «старик, одержимый рисунком» уже не мог держать кисть в руке.*
> Однако перед открывающими кавычками необходимая по структуре предложения запятая не опускается: *Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы».*

[Сочетания знаков препинания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175) (§ 66. Кавычки и другие знаки)

Странноватое предложение с использованием цитат (дословных выдержек из какого-либо текста) должно быть, думаю, оформлено так:

*Так, автор показывает, что мужчина, "обливаясь кровью" готов уйти из мира, "как висельник".*

Запятая нужна перед деепричастным оборотом, после него — нет.
Перед сравнительным оборотом "как висельник" запятая ставится.
*Актер на ролях забияки и хвастуна был худ, костляв, черен и сух, как висельник летом; кожа у него казалась пергаментом, наклеенным на костяк...* (Т. Готье. Капитан Фракасс).

P. S. Нешуточные споры по схожей ситуации были вот в этом вопросе:
[Нужна ли запятая при цитировании?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472394/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: А что насчет примера с вводной конструкцией? Там знаки препинания вполне себе ставились (тире): Он требовал пересмотреть работу — «поскольку я внёс нужные исправления» — и заново оценить её; Достаточно было бы одной просьбы — «помогите мне выпутаться из создавшегося положения», — и всё пошло бы по-другому.
Про запятые можно согласиться, да — их можно ставить по интонации, а не по правилам, если нужно; а насчет других знаков ничего не написано, да и правил на их счет и нет, скорее всего, — выбор остается за самим автором

Comment: В Вашем вопросе нет примера с вводной конструкцией. Цитирование — тема большая, особенная. А в одном ответе всё объять невозможно.

Comment: Но вопрос касался, хоть и не прямо, не только сравнительного, деепричастного оборота —  других тоже

Comment: Римма, вот я сегодня снова читал-читал эти правила и те споры. Ничё не понимаю... какое-то недоделанное правило, и даже искусственное. Примеры-то в нем понятные, но их мало, нет подходящих к "нашим" случаям. Ну как можно поставить запятую перед оборотом и не поставить ее после? При его изъятии что получится? Мне кажется, что нужно ставить обе запятые и ссылаться на тот пункт, где говорится о включении цитируемых слов в состав предложения в качестве его членов. Ну не знаю...

Comment: Я тоже *первоначально* так рассуждала (ты же ж видел — в первом ответе). Вся извертелася, иссомневалася...

Comment: Правило говорит про запятую, а тире не касается - все ж какое-то оно странное, ведь по сути в нем ничего не сказано про возможность постановки ЗП для интонации. И откуда эти правила берут?.. кажется, что это какая-то фантазия, а не твердый постулат

Comment: Там я оба ответа отметил сразу. А здесь пока сомневаюсь, но всё равно поддержу. Получается, что закрывающие кавычки съедают запятую; правила установлены, категоричны и потихоньку входят в мозг, гася сопротивление. :))  Но почему первая запятая ставится ввиду необходимости структуры предложения, а вторая нет? Необходимость отпала из-за кавычек? Странно это.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец После скобки закрывающую запятую не ставим. А кавычки как скобки. Поэтому так.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Так точно нельзя. Либо уже две запятые, либо ни одной. Это экзотический случай. Здесь лучше поставить обе запятые, так как конструкция открывается до кавычки (а не внутри цитаты), следовательно, закрыть её можно после кавычки. Правило основано на том, что открывающая запятая внутри цитаты, а здесь не так. Исправляйте! То есть здесь запятые относятся не к структуре цитаты, а к структуре внешнего предложения.

Comment: То есть весь смысл этого правила в том, чтобы не закрывать то, что открыто внутри цитаты (в чужом тексте). А здесь нет такого.

Comment: Стоп, а перед "как" же запятая не нужна, там же "в качестве".

Comment: Наверно, тем, кто не хочет исправлять ответ, надо ставить дизлайк. По-моему, вполне заслуженно. Как считаете?

Comment: Update: "обливаясь кровью" — фразеологизм, а они не обособляются по правилу Розенталя.

Comment: Перемудрили Вы... Конечно же, *обливаясь кровью* обособляется. *Несколько человек лежало на земле, обливаясь кровью* (Островский); *...полное веснушчатое лицо, обливаясь кровью, болезненно передергивалось* (Новиков-Прибой); *Обливаясь кровью, сторож рухнул у своей гостиницы* (Искандер); *Всадник вскрикнул и, как мешок, стал сползать с седла, обливаясь кровью* (Ладинский). (https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClgqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKNT74fLR1f4IQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCLAoqCigKA3JlcRIhCh/QvtCx0LvQuNCy0LDRj9GB0Ywg0LrRgNC%2B0LLRjNGOMAE=)

Comment: Стойте. В ваших примерах реальное облитие кровью. А в этом примере явно фразеологизм (переносное значение): https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сердце_кровью_обливается Окровавленный человек не сможет встать на стул...

Comment: Здесь о сильном чувстве жалости, негодования, сожаления...

Comment: Ну-у... это Вы так решили. Обливаясь кровью, можно не только на стул встать, но можно и бежать, и кататься, и даже прыгать. *Через некоторое время из дома выбежал, обливаясь кровью, Серый, за ним, припадая на обе ноги, ― Коленный* (Дворецкий); *Последний раз, когда она сидела на трибуне, я разбила на ее глазах колено и докатывалась, обливаясь кровью* (Бестемьянова...); *Так бы и шлепнуться ему на пол, обливаясь кровью, но бабкин кот прыгнул и повис на руке* (Трускиновская).

Comment: Обычно это о смертельном ранении. А в этих примерах похоже на гиперболу. Тогда надо у автора спросить. Но раненные люди не станут делать себе ещё хуже (нелогично). Тогда вторую запятую добавьте, оборот же открылся до цитаты, а не в ней.

Answer (score 1):

Пример текста: *Я, обливаясь кровью, встал на стул* (ЗАПЯТАЯ, сравнение) *как висельник*.

Использование цитирования: *Так, автор показывает, что мужчина "обливаясь кровью" готов уйти из мира "как висельник"*, -

цитирование отменяет оборот и сравнение, а кавычки указуют на дословное воспроизведение. Мы закавыченное "выбрасываем" из предложения как фишку со звёздочкой или джокер. Пунктуации не мешает.

*...мужчина (ля-ля) готов уйти из мира (ля-ля).*

Comment: Галина, автор вопроса спрашивает, по какому правилу. Мне тоже интересно, искал – не нашёл. Мы можем и обособленные фрагменты выбросить из предложения, и при этом знаки исчезают.

Comment: Однако заключенная в кавычки вводная конструкция может обособляться запятыми по Розенталю:
*Он требовал пересмотреть работу — «поскольку я внёс нужные исправления» — и заново оценить её; Достаточно было бы одной просьбы — «помогите мне выпутаться из создавшегося положения», — и всё пошло бы по-другому*

Comment: Можно предположить, что обособление любыми другими знаками препинания для интонационных целей возможно. Так, если предложение требует обособления: «Мужчина встал, вышел и — "обливаясь кровью", ушел из мира "как висельник"».

Comment: *Однако заключенная в кавычки вводная конструкция может обособляться знаками препинания...

Comment: Ребяты, ну какое правило, а? "Сделайте мне красиво" - вот и всё правило. Дышать должен не перегруженный знаками текст. Или -  пусть любое оформление сделает его дышащим.

Comment: Правил на самом деле много - ни дыхнуть ни пернуть

Comment: Ориентируемся на эстетику подачи!

Comment: Чего это цитирование отменяет оборот? А сравнения нет, там "в качестве".

Comment: *...мужчина (ля-ля) готов уйти из мира (ля-ля).*

Comment: Это точно лучше, чем вариант с одной запятой (Риммы, он ужасен), но правильнее запятые оставить, так как они внешние, а не внутри цитаты.

Comment: НееетЪ. Мои "ля-ля" не допускают знаков.

Comment: Может, тогда свой язык создать, как Заменгоф?)

Comment: Почему непременно свой язык? Я же вокруг объяснений танцую. И нахожу свои "ля-ля" весьма изячными для замены на что угодно - слово или оборот. Но никем не оценено...

Comment: Галина! Мне сейчас показался интересным такой подход и видение. Поддерживаю.

Comment: Оборот не перестаёт быть оборотом из-за кавычек. А кавычки внешние запятые не отменяют. Но сейчас заметил, что "обливаясь кровью" — фразеологизм, а они не обособляются (по правилу Розенталя). Но уместно ударение на нём и вставочная интонация, то есть обособить тоже можно, зависит от задумки автора. Но здесь ещё нужно глагол рассматривать, а оборот с ним не очень сочетается, что в пользу обособления. Всё оказалось гораздо сложнее... Так что получается, что ваш вариант верный, но не мысль о "ля-ля".

Comment: Саше Стрельцу - мерсейшее боку, а Олидду - некоторое фи за упёртость: то, что закавычено, - монолит, оно не расчленяется на обороты и не слушается внешних приказов, только внутренних (если бы цитата была сколь-либо распространённой, со "своими" знаками).

Comment: Ваш вариант заслуживает внимания, но другой правильнее, так как цитата открывается до оборота. Уверен, что академики выбрали бы этот вариант. Такой пример: *Он танцевал "как профессионал".* Как здесь понять, подобно профессионалу или будучи им (в качестве)? Такая пунктуация, ведущая к двусмысленности, недопустима! Или: *Он хочет, "чтобы все давали правильные ответы".* Не ставить запятую перед "чтобы"? Нет, цитаты обособляются, как обычный текст, так как они встраиваются в него и соединяются с ним синтаксически, иначе будет куча двусмысленностей и других проблем!

Comment: Из правила Розенталя: Однако перед открывающими кавычками необходимая по структуре предложения запятая не опускается: *Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы».* Запятая перед "как" не опускается! То же и в других случаях.