# Нужна ли запятая после закрывающей кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, кавычки, цитирование

Нужна ли запятая после кавычки, то есть для закрытия оборота "оснащённой кондиционером"? Какое правило тут действует?

*От этих бесконечных реплик а-ля "Хоть бы кто сказал спасибо его машине, оснащённой кондиционером"(,) уже голова шла кругом.*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли запятая при цитировании?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472394/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое (о запятой)

Она не нужна. Здесь используется такое правило Розенталя ([Сочетания знаков препинания. Кавычки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178#pp178)):

> **6.** Если предложение или словосочетание, заключенное в кавычки, должно было бы заканчиваться запятой, но дальше следует продолжение текста, то запятая не ставится ни перед закрывающими кавычками, ни после них: *Стихи «Ты знаешь край, где всё обильем дышит» знакомы нам с детства; Но вот пришло время, когда «старик, одержимый рисунком» уже не мог держать кисть в руке.*
> Однако перед открывающими кавычками необходимая по структуре предложения запятая не опускается: *Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы».*

Похожие вопросы уже были:
[Нужна ли запятая при цитировании?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472394/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)
[Цитирование оборотов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473505/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Второе (о словечке [**а-ля**](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8F))

Имеются сомнения — правильно ли оно использовано (с предложением)?
Обычно употребляется с существительным или словосочетанием (в И. п.):
*Причёска **а-ля мужик**. Кафтан **а-ля казак*** (из словаря);
*Татуировщик оказался черным сухощавым мужчиной с курчавой бородкой, в розовой вязаной кепке **а-ля Боб Марли*** (Виктор Пелевин);
*...причёска благодаря усилиям шаловливого ветра превратилась в вольную композицию **а-ля встрёпанная галка*** (Татьяна Рабинская).

Хотя... Хотя нашлось в Нацкорпусе вот такое предложение: *А-ля «Я у мамы дурочка» была причесана главная героиня комедии Марианна* (Н. Б. Лебина).

Comment: Да, "а-ля" требует конкретики, а предложения передают образ. И в словарях "кого-чего-нибудь". Правильным было бы указание человека, который так говорит. А здесь нужно слово "типа".