# Как пунктуационно правильно? Думаю, что 1 вариант

Tags: пунктуация

`1. Предложение «Я обещал, что я приду» написано на русском языке.`

`2. Предложение «Я обещал, что я приду», написано на русском языке.`

`3. Предложение «я обещал, что я приду» написано на русском языке.`

`4. Предложение «я обещал, что я приду», написано на русском языке.`

Comment: Как можно сомневаться?

Comment: Ну, я думал, что, возможно, надо как-то с *двух* сторон оборот с союзом *что* в кавычкообразном, или закавыченном, предложении обособить-таки.

Comment: Аа, тогда вам сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472394

Comment: Спасибо, сэр-пэр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильная запись: *Предложение **«Я обещал, что я приду»** написано на русском языке.*

Слово "предложение" является **приложением** по отношению к содержанию (какое предложение?), написание раздельное, знаками не выделяется.

Это **простое** предложение, предикативная основа – ***предложение написано***. Соответственно знаков препинания нет.

**Прописная** буква используется при цитировании целого предложения (похожий пример с прописной буквы есть **[у Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159)):**

*Он вспомнил **пословицу** «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана*.

Comment: Стоп, а так можно? То есть можно опустить двоеточие и тире? Я думал, надо так: _Предложение: «Я обещал, что я приду» — написано на русском языке_.

Comment: Синтаксическая синонимия, возможны различные формы для одного и того же содержания. У автора нет вашего оформления, то есть вы хотите сказать, что все его варианты неверны?  Или что вы выбираете?

Comment: В данном случае дословное  высказывание может являться членом предложения и оформляться по общим правилам для этого предложения.

Comment: @Максим В данном случае мы не ставим двоеточие. Сравните, однако, такую структуру, где, поскольку есть обобщающее слово *это*, мы должны поставить и двоеточие и тире: *Это предложение: «Я обещал, что я приду» — написано на русском языке.*

Comment: Нельзя исключить и такую запись: Это предложение, «Я обещал, что я приду».  написано на русском языке.  Такой стиль ближе к разговорному.  Дословное высказывание здесь также является членом предложения.

Comment: У Розенталя есть интересное правило про это: https://i.imgur.com/KjejfGK.png

Comment: Я знаю это правило;  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159 Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:

Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные…» (П.); Мимо станции проносились скорые поезда с табличками на вагонах: «Москва — Владивосток»; Разберите предложение: «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».   На там немного другая тема (предложение упоминается в тексте).